# selected value empty even marked as selected in developer tool

Tags: javascript

When I output `user` element value it empty even it selected. Here is element from firefox inspector

```
<select name="user" data-default-opt="" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" class="selectized">
    <option value="17" selected="selected">Option1</option>
</select>
```

here is how I checking the value

```
...
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
 console.log( doc.getElementsByName("user")[0].value);
...
```

output empty. Also on submit value comes empty. How to fix that?

Comment: `style="display: none;"`?

Comment: what does the variable 'ifrm' refer to?

Comment: its iframe object

Comment: You are probably using a cross-origin iframe, in which case you cannot  select anything

Comment: I can its same domain I even can submit the form. But  with empty user field which is the problem. Do you think its because of display none? @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: Is the `doc` value correct?

Comment: console.log( doc.getElementsByName("user")[0]);  print <select name="user" data-default-opt="{\"id\":17,\"brand_id\":…er.gif?v=3.0.0-beta.2\"}">
alex.php:16:17